# Is there an add on for Sublime or Atom code editors that will let me quick edit functions called inside other functions?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I have just started my JavaScript learning and I'm picking it up, an annoyance is when a function calls another function inside it but sometimes that function has been defined above it, below or wherever there is some Extension/Add on that can follow the function to it's path and then keep a little tree hierarchy of the parent function so I can just jump back and forth to do edits and such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no possible way to build a kind of hierarchy of called functions during editing, but you can always switch to function declaration by pressing F12 (in sublime). Also you may find it useful to use  something like typescript compiler - it would provide you  with information about required parameters, return values, autocomplete and so on